# How to run code selection in Spyder without changing the active window to IPython console?

Tags: python, ipython, spyder

This is mostly a question regarding work-flow in Spyder, and not a pure programming question. If anyone thinks it has no place here, then please let me know and I'll remove it.

Here we go:

I'm running Spyder on a Windows 64-bit operating system. The interaction between the Spyder IDE and IPython console depends on how you choose to run your code, and I would like to specify how this interaction works.

Among several options to run parts of the code, the difference between the following two is what puzzles me:

**Option 1 - Select parts of the code and hit F9**

This runs the selected code. No surprise there.
Hit F9 again, and the same selection is executed once more.
[image]

**Option 2 - Run the same selection using Cells (#%%) and Ctrl+Enter**

The code is run just like before. But hit Ctrl-Enter again, and nothing happens. Probably because the IPython console now is the active window.
[image]

I would like to find some way of changing this so I can use Ctrl+Enter and run the cell contents multiple times without having to make the Spyder IDE the active window by manually clicking on it. I don't know if this is possible at all. Googling and messing around in the settings under **Run / configure** and **Tools / Preferences** has so far been useless.

Thank you for any suggestions!

P.S

In case you're wondering why this is such a big deal to me, I'm rendering multiple charts and exporting them to Power Point with minor changes each time the code is run. This way, new parts of the charts (lines, textboxes, etc) are revealed when I'm working my way through a finished Power Point presentation. And for my basic data science needs, this has turned out to be a pretty much optimal work-flow. Except, of course, that I have to manually select the Spyder IDE each time I run different selections of the code.

Comment: What version of Spyder are you running?

Comment: I left the laptop at work and I'm on a trip until monday, so I'm going to double check then. But I think I'm on the very latest version. Is there a difference between 3.1.3 and 3.1.4 when it comes to this? By the way, thank you for giving attention to what must seem like a minor detail to most people out there!

Comment: No problem :-) Just let me know what your version is to be sure what to do about this.

Comment: I'm on Spyder 3.1.4. I've been messing around a bit more, and there is one little detail that I was not aware of when I posted the question. In the example in the question, the IPython console is popped out from the Spyder main window. If I drag it back into the Spyder main window, I can run the same cell as many times as I want using Ctrl+Enter. I guess there could be many reasons why the interaction between the Spyder IDE and IPython Console is different in those two cases.

Comment: @Carlos Cordoba. Did you find the time to have a look at this again?

Comment: I don't know what could be causing this, sorry. Please open an issue in our [issue tracker](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues) so we don't forget to take a look at it in the future.

Comment: As someone who has come to Python from R, I am used to the way execution is done in R Studio.  There, you press Ctrl+Enter to execute the current block of code, which can be either the current line if that is a complete statement, or multiple lines if a statement is spread over more than one lines.  This doesn't seem to be possible in Spyder - F9 executes only the current line (or selected lines) and gives an error message if the statement continues across multiple lines.  Is there any way to get R Studio equivalent behaviour?

Comment: I am doing the same things (with shift enter and also a lot of f9), everyday I tell myself I should startup a jupyter notebook instead of running spyder, it supports this workflow much better (but old habits die slowly...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in **Option 2**, you should use **Shift+Enter** instead

Answer (score 3):

In the latest spyder version, the keyboard shortcut to run the highlighted lines of code is `F9` but it doesn't seem to work.

Go change it from `TOOLS>>PREFERENCES>>KEYBOARD SHORTCUTS` then double click on any shortcut you want to change and change with your shortcut. But be very careful if you used the same shortcut that is used for any other work then for that it will remove.

I changed the shortcut for **'run selection'** from `F9` to `ctrl + Enter`

Comment: it appears that you don't need to remap this any more, `ctrl + enter` works from  a fresh install. Matching RStudio shortcuts

Comment: actually, that's not the case, the default for `ctrl+enter` is to run the cell, which if you don't specify it, appears to be the whole program